# In Drupal, how to Create programmaticaly some nodes of a content type when created a node of another content type?

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal-7, drupal-modules, slickgrid

I would like to create an editable task table with slickgrid view, where each row is a node (of content type 2) that will be created automatically by a different content type (the 1st content type) or a webform.

Content type 1 - The 1st content type have 4 fields (this node will create automatically some nodes of the second content type)

1st - "Days" - is a Date field type - with **unlimited** (1 to 10) values

2nd - "City's" - is a Reference to a Term - with **unlimited** (1 to 10) values

3th - "Type of operation" is a Reference to a Term - with an unique value

4th - "Number of person by city" is a Integer field type - with an unique value

Content type 2 - the 2nd content type have those fields

1st - "Day" - is a Date field type - with an unique value

2nd - "City" - is a Reference to a Term - with an unique value

3th - "Type of operation" is a Reference to a Term - with an unique value

4th - "Name of a person" is a text field - with an unique value

Now for example if i create a node of Content type 1 with 5 values for the date field and 5 for the City's and the number "2" for the integer field, it will create automatically **5*5*2= 50 nodes** of Content type 2, the "name of a person" field will be created empty of course.

I think i must create a module or perhaps with rules it's possible ?  is it possible to replace the content type 1 by a webform?
I'm newbie in drupal module developement. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a module for your problem.

For "Content type 1" data you don't use "webform" but "entity form" the evolution of webform (if I can say it). This type of form use fields, the same of "node", but it is connect to rules, so when a form is submitted you can set a rule (or more) to be execute. You need to create this "rule" in your module.

M.

ps: sorry for my bad english.